# FullCalendar Start/End time viewable?

Tags: json, fullcalendar

Good afternoon, could anyone point me in right direction, despite reading all docs and searching I'm stuck. I use JSON to insert mysql data into the calendar, this appears ok but as I cant open the events the user doesnt know how long the event is.

We need to allow users to add events by the day or hour, for example meeting is at 14:00 until 15:30. I had planned to use my own form for event input and I have 4 columns dat_start, dat_end, time_start & time_end that are populated.

I just need a way for end users to be able to see times on these events, is there a way I can have an event clickable it pops up a window with event info?

My code is called via a js file which contains:

```
//===== Calendar =====//

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        startParam: 'start',
            endParam: 'end',
        editable: true,
        events : {
            url: 'json-events.php',
            async: 'false'
            }
    });
```

Many thanks

Gary

Answer (score 1):

Which version of FullCalendar are you using? I'm using 1.5.3 but the technique I use I think can be used in earlier versions. Basically I feed back extra fields from my database via the json feeds. I then use some code I picked up from stackoverflow that uses qtips to format and attach this extra information to the events. When a user hovers over the event the extra data is displayed. Just do a search for FullCalendar and qTip tags.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for reply.I am also using 1.5.3, I've yet to see an example allowing data input via the actual dayclick on fullcal, is that possible then? I spent a day trying to get qTip working but gave up as had no success, I included the qTip js file and like you copied some code to call it but nothing happened. Have you any working code you could possibly share with me? Many thanks again.